# Can not desplay my JSON data in Nextjs when doing a fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am not understand what the code is meaning also the api is public for anyone to see it is a simple json

Error I am getting

```
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

index.jsx doing the fetch call

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const {test} = await fetch("https://gorestfulapi-production.up.railway.app/api/movies").then(x => x.json());
  
  return {
    props: {
      test: test,

    }
  }
}

export default function Home({ test})   {
  console.log('test',test);
  return (
    <div className="">


      <main className="">
        <h1 className="">
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>
     {test}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `test` in `const {test} = await fetch` does not exist.

You are trying to destructure the response json object, but it likely misses a `test` field, hence it's undefined.

Nextjs requires server side props NOT to be undefined.